# Unable to identify the webelements on XHTML page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xhtml, selenium-chromedriver

Unable to identify the webelements on XHTML page

In My project if I click on a link a PDF opens up in a new tab and I am trying to download the PDF by clicking on Download click.The Web Element is not getting identified as the download icon is on the XHTML page. I have tried replicating this using India Post website. Still unable to identify the element. Below is the code. Does anyone have a solution?

```
package com.demo.learn;

    import java.util.Set;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class handle {

    public static void main (String [] args){
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://CAHCO Automation//OpteamixAutomation-master(1)//OpteamixAutomation-master//Automation_framework//OPTEAMIX//Drivers//chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/Form.aspx");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_29491a13_ee77_4e11_a5e4_e031cc13d245']/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a/img")).click();
        Set<String> handles=driver.getWindowHandles();
        String firsthandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        handles.remove(firsthandle);
        String winhandle = handles.iterator().next();
        if (winhandle!=firsthandle){
             String secondWinHandle = winhandle;
             driver.switchTo().window(secondWinHandle);
             System.out.println("Switched");
             boolean display = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
      [@id='download']")).isDisplayed();
             if(display==true)
             {
                 System.out.println("Displayed");
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Not Displayed");
             }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant `HTML`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to do is clicking on PDF viewer in Chrome. The Chrome PDF viewer is a Chrome plugin so you cannot access it.
I recommend a workaround by adding an attribute to the link to open PDF. The attribute `download` will tell web browser to download it instead of open it in PDF Viewer. See my code below.

```
String script = "document.querySelector('#ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_29491a13_ee77_4e11_a5e4_e031cc13d245>div>table>tbody>tr>td>a>img').setAttribute('download','name-of-the-download-file-recommend-guid-or-timestamp.pdf');";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_29491a13_ee77_4e11_a5e4_e031cc13d245']/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a/img")).click();
```

Please note that the Css Selector in my example `#ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_29491a13_ee77_4e11_a5e4_e031cc13d245>div>table>tbody>tr>td>a>img` is just an example which was converted from your XPath. It might find an incorrect element.